# Discord.js Coronavirus Cases Bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How can I make the code work for every country?
Right now I just coded the bot, so It can answer !corona with the corona confirmed cases of germany.

Here is the code:

```
bot.on('message', msg=>{
if(msg.content === '!corona'){
    const url = "https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries/germany"
    req(url, function(err, response, body){
        if(err) return msg.reply("err")
        body = JSON.parse(body)
        msg.reply(`Corona Fälle für: + \*\*${body.cases}\*\*\ ` ,)
    }


,)}
```

Comment: are you looking to change the country dynamically or as a parameter of the message?

Answer (score 1):

You can add support for arguments in your commands and then using that you can take the user's input to check different countries accordingly.

Your solution would be:

```js
bot.on('message', msg => {
const prefix = '!';
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

if(command === 'corona') {
    if (!args[0]) return message.reply('you need to enter a country name')
    const url = `https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries/${args[0]}`
    req(url, function(err, response, body){
        if(err) return msg.reply("err")
        body = JSON.parse(body)
        msg.reply(`Corona Fälle für: + \*\*${body.cases}\*\*\ ` ,)
    }


,)}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
I tired the switch case way and now i also tried your solution.
Now I know what I did wrong, you helped me :)